# Загрузка фото PHP

Tags: php

мой вопрос заключается в следующем.

Допустим, есть сайт site.ru , на сайте есть форма для загрузки изображений, как мне со своего сайта загрузить изображения на site.ru и получить результат?

Исходник не прошу конечно писать, но на примеры бы посмотрела, ну или просто подскажите в каком направлении двигаться, спасибо

Comment: Сформулируйте Ваш вопрос более конструктивно.

Comment: Есть на стороннем сайте страница, на которой есть форма, для загрузки фото, после загрузки фото , на той же странице появляются результаты обработки ранее загруженной фотографии. Так вот, вопрос в том, как реализовать эту загрузку фото через php и просить результаты обработки

Comment: `cURL`-ом шлете запрос с вашими данными, в том числе и файлом. В ответ получаете страницу результата. Парсите ее html-парсером, находите нужное и далее.

Comment: 503 ошибку возвращает при попытке загрузки файла

Comment: Вы каким способом загружаете, что у Вам возвращается 503?

Answer (score 0):

Пример использования для отправки файла на GPSIES.COM

Авторизация

```
$config['gpsies_password'] = "password";
$config['gpsies_login'] = "login";

$ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");   
$curl=curl_init("http://www.gpsies.com/login.do?username=". $config['gpsies_login'] ."&password=". $config['gpsies_password']);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY,1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile); 
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec_follow($curl);

if($result) {
    //trigger_error ("Auth OK\r\n<hr>");
} else {
    trigger_error ("Auth Error\r\n<hr>");
}
curl_close($curl);
```

Формирую строку запроса (данные взяты из полей формы отправки)

```
    $link = 'https://mysite.ru/;
    $name = "File_Name"; 

    $fields = array(
        "language"          => 'ru',
        "trackAsString"     => '',
        "maxTrackpoints"    => 3000,
    //  "filename"          => sanitize_title_with_translit($name),
        "filename"          => $name,
        "status"            => 1, 
        "fileDescription"   => 'Track for: https://mysite.ru/', 
        "trackTypes"        => 'biking',
        "websiteUrl"        => 'https://mysite.ru/',
        //"trackClassifications"    => '',  
        //"trackCharacters"     => '',
        "trackAttributes"   => 'gpsRecorded',
        //"trackRoadbeds"       => '',
        //"trackRoads"      => '',
        "startpointCountry" => 'RU',
        "endpointCountry"   => 'RU',
        //"viceVersa"       => '',
        "trackSimplification" => 0,
        //"addElevation"        => '',  
        "formFileUrl"       => $link, 
        "uploadButton"      => 'save',
    );

    foreach ($fields as $key => $value) 
    {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));

        if ($key == 'formFileUrl' && ($value == 'http%3A%2F%2F' || $value == ''))
        {
            return ;
        }
        $aQueryStrs[] .= "$key=$value";
    }
    $query_string = implode('&',$aQueryStrs);

    $fields_str = http_build_query($fields);
```

Отправляю запрос:

```
if ($curl=curl_init("http://www.gpsies.com/upload.do;l=ru?". $query_string)) {
    //curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.gpsies.com/upload.do");
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER,1); 
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY,0); 
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile); 
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.gpsies.com/login.do");

} else {
    trigger_error ("No init CURL");
}
```

Получаю обратно странцу с ответом (как при обычной загрузке на том сайте) в т.ч проверяю open_basedir и safe_mode

```
if (ini_get('open_basedir') == '' && ini_get('safe_mode' == 'Off'))
    {
        curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $l);
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
    }
    else
    {
        $result = curl_exec_follow($curl);
    }

    if(curl_errno($curl))
    {
        trigger_error ("Error Occured in Curl\n<br />Error number: " .curl_errno($curl) ."\n == ".curl_error($curl)."\n<br>");
    }
    if($result) {

        // Info
        $header_info = curl_getinfo($curl,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
        $header_size = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
        $header = substr($result, 0, $header_size);
        $body = substr($result, $header_size);
        //End Info

        // DEBUGER +
        //$out .= "POST<hr><p>Header Sent: " . $header_info ."</p><hr>
        //              <p>Header Received: " . $header . "</p><hr>
        //              <p>Body: ". $body . "</p><hr>";
        // END DEBUGER +
    } else {
        trigger_error ("<hr>FILE ERROR\r\n<hr>");
    }
```

Разлогиниваюсь на том сайте

```
$curl=curl_init("http://www.gpsies.com/login.do?logout=true");
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY,1);
   if(curl_exec($curl)) {
        //trigger_error ( "EXIT OK\r\n<hr>");
    } else {
        trigger_error ("EXIT Error\r\n<hr>");
    }

curl_close($curl);
unlink($ckfile) or die("Can't unlink $ckfile");
```

Далее, если нужна дальнейшая обработки страницы ответа, парсите `$body`